# How to run mocha tests from inside the Brackets editor

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, adobe-brackets

At the moment I have to keep a terminal open and it would be great if I could run them from inside brackets.

In fact even better would be to control which tests ones get executed from inside the UI (like what happens for Resharper inside VisualStudio).

And the ideal scenario would be to show code coverage for those tests (like VisualStudio NCrunch does)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything Mocha-specific, but here are a few Brackets extensions that could be helpful:

- [Karma Runner extension](https://github.com/artoale/karma-brackets) - Karma is a generic test-runner and it [supports Mocha](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma#but-i-still-want-to-use-_insert-testing-library_).
- [Command Line Shortcuts extension](https://github.com/antivanov/Brackets-Command-Line-Shortcuts) - Instead of keeping a terminal open, you can use a keyboard shortcut in Brackets to launch the same command.
- [Brackets Terminal extension](https://github.com/artoale/brackets-terminal) - Instead of keeping a terminal window open, you can use a panel within Brackets to run terminal commands.
- I think the [xUnit extension](https://github.com/brackets-xunit/brackets-xunit) displays code coverage, but it currently only works with Jasmine, qUnit, or YUI tests.